# TypeError: where() received an invalid combination of arguments

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification

I want to make a judgment on the value predicted by the neural network. If it is greater than 0.5, it is 1, and if it is less than 0.5, it is 0.When I ran my model,I met this problem.

```
Input In [73], in create_model(n_inputs)
     45 a = torch.ones(n_inputs,1)
     46 b = torch.zeros(n_inputs,1)
---> 48 indicator_output = torch.where(indicator_probability>0.5, a, b)

TypeError: where() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor condition)
 * (Tensor condition, Tensor input, Tensor other, *, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor condition, Number self, Tensor other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor)
 * (Tensor condition, Tensor input, Number other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor)
 * (Tensor condition, Number self, Number other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (Tensor, Tensor, Tensor)
```

My code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as k
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers,Model,callbacks,Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import GRU,LSTM,Layer,LayerNormalization,Input,Conv1D,Embedding,Flatten,RepeatVector,GlobalAveragePooling1D,Masking,concatenate,TimeDistributed,Dense,Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Lambda
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam,rmsprop
from tensorflow.python.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import Constant
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
print('Tensorflow version: {}'.format(tf.__version__))


def create_model(n_inputs):

  all_inputs = Input(shape=(n_inputs, 2),name = "all_inputs")
    
  dense1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
  dropout = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2))
  dense2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  

  indicator_probability = dense2(dropout(dense1(outputs)))
  a = torch.ones(n_inputs,1)
  b = torch.zeros(n_inputs,1)

  indicator_output = torch.where(indicator_probability>0.5, a, b)
  
  model = Model(inputs=all_inputs, outputs=indicator_output)

  return model

prediction_model = create_model(n_inputs=11)
prediction_model.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

I didn't know why this problem happended.Hope to get a solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I didn't know why this problem happended" - well, did you **read** the error message? What do you think it means? (because you are using Tensorflow, I assume you at least understand what a tensor is.) Where the code says `torch.where(indicator_probability>0.5, a, b)`, what do you think is the **type** of `indicator_probability>0.5`? Of `a`? Of `b`? Do you see how that relates to the description in the error message? See how it also lists allowed combinations of types for the arguments? Does one of those make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image] The first tensor is an impostor!

You are mixing Tensorflow and Pytorch.
You used a `tensorflow.python.keras.layers.Dense` to create the dense layer. Only **PyTorch** tensors transform into **TensorCondition** when used in a condition. So here you obtained a `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` instead:

```
  dense2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
  indicator_probability = dense2(dropout(dense1(outputs)))
  torch.where(indicator_probability>0.5, a, b) # HERE! Condition a > b
```

`indicator_probability>0.5` dit did not turn into a **TensorCondition**.

*where()* expected `(TensorCondition, Tensor, Tensor)` but got instead a `(TensorFlow Tensor, PyTroch Tensor, Pytorch Tensor)`, which he proceeded to display as `(Tensor, Tensor, Tensor)`, hiding the datatype of the first attribute.

Comment: But I still received an error when I changed it to this:`a = torch.ones(n_inputs,1)\
 b = torch.zeros(n_inputs,1)\
greater = indicator_probability > 0.5\
less = indicator_probability == 0.5\
  greater_less = tf.logical_or(greater,less)  \
    
  indicator_output = torch.where(greater_less, a, b)`

Comment: @TheresaLiu try `type(indicator_probability)? ` and see what type you obtain. If it's not a Tensor, you know why it doesn't work. :)

Comment: I got `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer, I did confuse tensorflow Tensor and Pytorch Tensor, I think I know how to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to check where `indicator_probability>0.5` then it's `1`, else, `0`. Then, you just need a simple line:

```py
indicator_output = torch.where(indicator_probability>0.5, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Also I must admit that the [docs of torch.where](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) is confusing...

Comment: this is what I want to express

Comment: If you see that it answers your question, consider marking it as "Correct answer" for others to see :)